How does standard text search work across languages, with respect to problems like vowels in Hebrew?
In Hebrew, the vowels (nikkud) are optional and, when included, are written around the main text. For example, the name Miriam is מרים without vowels or מִרְיָם with vowels (note the little dots and dashes added underneath). Vowels are used only in specific contexts (to help beginners, for unusual or ambiguous words, for certain religious contexts, etc).
When typing Hebrew, the vowels are Unicode modifiers. I.e. you type the base letter, then you type the vowel.
The interesting part is that text search in some applications seems to totally ignore nikkud. For example, in Chrome, searching either version of Miriam on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miriam_(given_name) matches both versions. Extra interestingly, searching something like מַר, which has different vowels than Miriam but is a subset of Miriam when you only consider the consonants, does match Miriam. So, even text that is actually different will match if it's the same after removing nikkud.
My understanding is that Arabic has a similar system of optional vowels.
Is there any standard "correct" way to implement search across many languages? Expanding from this example, my hypothesis is that the norm is for search to ignore all Unicode modifiers and accept that you get some false positives, but perhaps software tends to special case each language? It seems like it would be most correct, at least in Hebrew, to allow for a optional wildcard nikkud on any letter that is not followed by a nikkud, but when nikkud is given, it cannot match different nikkud. However, I see why you wouldn't want to bother implementing that.
